# For Each in View?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different tables, they are:

> user - uid, name, age, phonenumber
>
> rating - score, raterid, uid

In rating table, basically there can be different rater that can rate the same user.

```
Example: raterid 009 gives "10" to uid 001; raterid 008 gives "5" to uid 001.
```

Now, I'm trying to create a view that display the user's name, age and also the average score.

However, isn't I need somekind of "FOR EACH" (like in trigger) to able to search all of the scores that a particular "uid" has?

Here's my code so far, however I prints "ERROR FUNCTION"

```
CREATE VIEW theBestSeller AS
SELECT U.name, U.age, AVG(R.score)
FROM USER U, RATING R
WHERE U.uid = R.uid
GROUP BY AVG(R.score)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

First, learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN`.  Then you need to aggregate correctly:

```
CREATE VIEW theBestSeller AS
    SELECT U.name, U.age, AVG(R.score)
    FROM USER U JOIN
        RATING R
        ON U.uid = R.uid
    GROUP BY U.name, U.age;
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback about join syntax. I learnt that from someone else too. Anyway, the mistake is because I typed `"GROUP BY (AVG(...))"` instead of `U.name`?